# A formula related to the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse of Hilbert space operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $E$ an **infinite dimensional** complex Hilbert space and $\mathcal{L}(E)$  be the algebra of all bounded linear operators on $E$.

**Definition:** Let $T \in \mathcal{L}(E)$. The Moore-Penrose inverse of $T$, denoted by $T^{+}$, is defined as the unique linear extension of $(\bar{T})^{-1}$ in
 $$D(T^{+}) = \mathcal{R}(T)+\mathcal{R}(T)^{\perp},$$
with $\mathcal{N}(T^{+}) = \mathcal{R}(T)^{\perp}$ and  $\bar{T}$ is the isomorphism
$$\bar{T}:=T|_{{\mathcal{N}(T)}^{\perp}}: {\mathcal{N}(T)}^{\perp} \longrightarrow   \mathcal{R}(T).$$
Moreover, $T^{+}$ is the unique solution of the four ''Moore-Penrose equations'':
$$TXT = T,\quad XTX = X,\quad XT = P_{N{(T)^{\bot}}}\,\,\mbox{and}\,\,\quad TX = P_{\overline{\mathcal{R}(T)}}{{|}_{D(T^{+})}}.$$

Here $\mathcal{R}(T)$ and $\mathcal{N}(T)$ denote respectively the range and the nullspace of $T$. Also $P_{F}$ denote the orthogonal projection onto $F$.

> It is well know that $A^+$ is bounded iff $A$ has a closed range.
>
> - If $A$ is selfadjoint matrix, then
>     $$ A^{+}= \lim_{t \to 0}(A^2+tI)^{-1} A.\;\;(1).$$
> - If $A$ is not selfadjoint, then $A^+=A^*(AA^*)^+$ (which is equal to $(A^*A)^+A^*$).
>
> Is the formula $(1)$ true only for matrix or even for Hilbert space operators? Let for example $S$ an operator on $\ell^2$ given by 
>   $$S(x_1,x_2,\cdots)=(x_1,\tfrac{1}{2} x_2,\tfrac{1}{3} x_3,\cdots).$$
>   How can I find $S^+$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What may be tripping you up here is that $T^+$, as you have defined it, could be unbounded, if the range of $T$ is not closed. So the answer to

> Is the formula (1) true only for matrix or even for Hilbert space operators?

is ... sort of, depending on what you mean by taking a limit. I'm not sure there's any standard notion of convergence for unbounded operators. But you can make sense of (1) as a strong limit on the domain of $T^+$.

Your second question is easier: $S^+(x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots) = (x_1, 2x_2, 3x_3, \ldots)$, with domain the set of sequences in $l^2$ for which that target sequence also belongs to $l^2$.

Comment: Please Professor, is the formula $(1)$ well known in the literature? If yes, could you please provide me a name of a reference. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Student: see the comment by user131781. You only have to check it for diagonal matrices. Try this, it's easy.

Answer (score 1):

This is an addendum to the above answer, but too long for a comment.  Firstly, there is a very simple proof if one is prepared to use the spectral theorem in the form that each (possibly unbounded) self-adjoint operator is representable as multiplication by a measurable function $x$ on an $L^2$-space.  Then the Moore-Penrose inverse is multiplication by the function which is $\dfrac 1 x$ on the set where $x$ is non-zero and $0$ otherwise.  As regards the convergence, the one mentioned in the response has the disadvantage that it depends on the operator.  However, there is a natural topology on the space of observables (i.e., unbounded, self-adjoint operators on a Hilbert space) under which it is a Polish space (for separable Hilbert spaces) and under which your question has a positive response. This is the relevant one for working with the observables (which play, in quantum theory, the role of the real numbers), typically in questions involving the key notion of perturbation theory (of which your question is a typical example).

Comment: I don't understand how to prove the formula $(1)$ even for matrix. I hope that you can give me hints. Thank you.

Comment: By the spectral theorem, you can assume that the matrix is diagonal. Then the computations are very transparent.

Comment: What is the natural topology on unbounded self-adjoint operators?

Comment: It is a bit complicated to explain, certainly beyond the scope of a comment or answer here. If you are really interested, I could continue this exchange by mail.

Comment: How about a reference, or even better, a couple of sentences which express the idea behind it?

Comment: There are complete analogues of the Riesz representation and Gelfand-Naimark theories for compact spaces to the non compact case if one replaces $C(K)$ with the space of bounded continuous functions, not regarded as a Banach spce but as a so-called Saks spce with the strict topology which was introduced by R.C.Buck.  Continuing in this direction, the spectral theorem can be restated as the fact that the space of observables is identical with a kind of generalised spectum, namily the family of continuous, linear homomorphisms from the algebra of bounded continuous functions on the line

Comment: to $L(H)$, both of these spaces to be interpreted not as Banach spaces but as Saks spaces (reference for the precise details: J.B. Cooper, Saks spaces and applications to functional analysis).  This representation leads to a natural definition of the topology I mentioned and which, I would claim, is the correct one for dealing  with the space of observables, a claim which could be sustantiated by listing some of its properies—not an option on this forum.

Comment: Wow, thank you. I never heard of this before.